# Solving ODE using Laplace transformation without table of transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Solve $$y'' + 4y' -5y = 2xe^{-3x}$$ using the Laplace transform method. For the the Laplace transform of the ODE you must do the integration (do not use table).

Table can be only used when computing the inverse Laplace transform.

So, I started with that:

$$y'' + 4y' -5y = 2xe^{-3x}$$

If $y = e^{ax}$ , then $y'' = ae^{ax}$

inf int $0 = ae^{ax}\cdot e^{-sx} dx$

Comment: No, that's a point. I've done this DE by the table, but have no idea how to implement it by integration

Comment: Well, the expression is Y(s) (s^2 -4s -5) = 1/(s+3)^2 +8 +2s

Comment: Y(s) = 1/((s^2-4s-5)*(s+3)^2) + (8+2s)/(s^2-4s-5)

Comment: suppose that $y$ has a $C^2$ solution which $\to 0$ (and $y'$ and $y''$ too) as $x\to \infty$. hence we can write for $Re(s) > 0$ : $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty (y''(x) + 4y'(x) - 5y(x)) e^{-sx} dx = \int_0^\infty  x e^{-3x} e^{-sx} dx$. then integrate by part two times $\int_0^\infty y''(x)e^{-sx} dx$ and one time $\int_0^\infty y'(x)e^{-sx} dx$ to get  $Y(s) (s^2-4s+5) + \ldots y(0) =\ldots$, solve the obtained equation, inverse Laplace transform, and at the end make everything rigorous, by saying "yes $y(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$", so the supposition made at the beginning was acceptable.

Comment: Partial fraction form :  Y(s) = -1/(24s + 24) + 5/(128(s+3)) + 1/(16(s+3)^2) + 1/(384(s-5)) + 3/(s-5) - 1/(s+1)

Comment: user1952009 Thanks! will try it now